# Using For Loop with BeautifulSoup to Select Text on a Different URLs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been scratching my head for nearly 4 days trying to find the best way to loop through a table of URLs on one website, request the URL and scrape text from 2 different areas of the second site.

I have tried to rewrite this script multiple times, using several different solutions to achieve my desired results, however, I have not been able to fully accomplish this.

Currently, I am able to select the first link of the table on page one, to go to the new page and select the data I need but I cant get the code to continue to loop through every link on the first page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

journal_site = "https://journals.sagepub.com"
site_link 'http://journals.sagepub.com/action/showPublications?
pageSize=100&startPage='

# each page contains 100 results I need to scrape from 
page_1 = '0'
page_2 = '1'
page_3 = '3'
page_4 = '4'

journal_list = site_link + page_1
r = requests.get(journal_list)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for table_row in soup.select('div.results'):
    journal_name = table_row.findAll('tr', class_='False')
    journal_link = table_row.find('a')['href']
    journal_page = journal_site + journal_link

    r = requests.get(journal_page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    for journal_header, journal_description in zip(soup.select('main'), 
    soup.select('div.journalCarouselTextText')):
        try:
            title = journal_header.h1.text.strip()
            description = journal_description.p.text.strip()
            print(title,':', description)
        except AttributeError:
            continue
```

What is the best way to find the title and the description for every journal_name? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your code works for me, just needed to modify the middle section of the code, leaving the parts before and after the same:

```
# all code same up to here

journal_list = site_link + page_1
r = requests.get(journal_list)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find("div", { "class" : "results" })

table = results.find('table')

for row in table.find_all('a', href=True):
    journal_link = row['href']
    journal_page = journal_site + journal_link

    # from here same as your code
```

I stopped after it got the fourth response(title/description) of 100 results from the first page. I'm pretty sure it will get all the expected results, only needs to loop through the 4 subsequent pages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! The process you took is very clear now, I appreciate the detail!